# PHP - Check $string to see if it contains a $string but NOT multiple other $strings

Tags: php, string

I am trying to work out whether or not a $string contains a particular $string and NOT contain multiple other $strings... I need to assign a code depending on what colors are involved..
just balloon = 1, red = 2, blue = 3, green = 4, red blue = 5, red green = 6, blue green = 7,
red blue green = 11 (all colours)
*this has been simplified for this example as there are 6 colours and I have to repeat this for 10 objects...*

I thought I could use some sort of combimation of stros & preg_match:

```
$mystring = "red blue balloon";
    if((strpos($mystring, 'red') !== false) {$code = 2;} 
        else if((strpos($mystring, 'blue') !== false) {$code = 3;} 
        else if(preg_match('(red|blue)', $mystring) === 1) {$code = 5;} // etc for each perm
        else {$code = 1;} // just balloon
```

but I realised that this code doesn't really work and it will require many lines of code for each permutaion...

Is there a nice tidy way I can assign the codes. I have to repeat this with many colors and many different objects...

If you can point me in the right direction, I'd be very grateful. Thanks very much in advance

Comment: Is there a reason that you don't explode on spaces and check the existence of whole strings in the array?  Does your real data have punctuation in it?  Are the "words" actually words in your project?  If your sample data is not realistic enough, we might give you bad advice.  Should you start at the most difficult to satisfy and work your way down to the easiest? Do you account for every permutation of all six colors in your project?  I think I need clarifications. `/red|blue/` does not mean "red and blue" and `preg_match()` makes a max of one match.

Comment: The real data is a sentance with other words, not only the ones above, but these are the specific words I need to check for. So the sentance might say "The girls and boys are playing with a red and blue balloon in the park!"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can accumulate points as you check for individual words.  If all three colors are found, award 2 bonus points.  Your example is ambiguous about scoring the balloon, so I am interpreting your needs as only counting balloon if there are no colors.

You should use case-insensitivity for flexibility and word boundaries to ensure that you are matching whole words.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/YqtZG))

```
function getCode($string) {
    $code = 0;
    if (preg_match('/\bred\b/i', $string)) {
        $code += 2;
    }
    if (preg_match('/\bblue\b/i', $string)) {
        $code += 3;
    }
    if (preg_match('/\bgreen\b/i', $string)) {
        $code += 4;
    }
    if ($code === 9) {
        $code += 2;
    }
    if ($code) {
        return $code;
    }
    if (preg_match('/\bballoon\b/i', $string)) {
        return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}

$sentences = [
    'Here is a green, blue, and red balloon',
    'A blue balloon here',
    'A red herring',
    'Blue is the name of my dog',
    'Red and green are Xmas colors',
    'blue skies over green grass',
    'Foo is bar',
    'Have a balloon and a balloon and a balloon',
    'A green balloon',
    'A blue balloon with a red string',
];

foreach ($sentences as $sentence) {
    printf("%s => %d\n", $sentence, getCode($sentence));
}
```

Output:

```
Here is a green, blue, and red balloon => 11
A blue balloon here => 3
A red herring => 2
Blue is the name of my dog => 3
Red and green are Xmas colors => 6
blue skies over green grass => 7
Foo is bar => 0
Have a balloon and a balloon and a balloon => 1
A green balloon => 4
A blue balloon with a red string => 5
```

Comment: One minor improvement might be to assign a bitwise-safe integer value to each color (red = 2, blue = 4, green = 8), and use a simple mapping array to map the 'bitwise' value to the expected output. (i.e. 2=>2, 4=>3, 8=>4, 12=>5, etc). This way, you can change out the expected values without having to change up every hardcoded value in the function.

Comment: I am not in control of the value assigned to each word.  Oh, do you mean translate the words then map the counts.  Meh, I don't know if it's worth it.

Comment: @user33 I am not sure what you expect regarding `balloon` values.  is that meant to be simply added to the total like the colors?  Can you please clarify your expected results for all of my sample sentences?  Even if my answer doesn't perfectly align with your actual requirements, you should be able to follow the technique and adjust as needed.

Comment: Brilliant! Thanks very much Mick - this is a brilliant solution - I shall implement it now!

Comment: Please don't leave your question in this ambiguous state.  Please take the time to clarify your exact requirements or this page may be prone to being deleted for being low-quality.  Please edit your question.  What should happen if a color is mentioned more than once in the sentence?